# Debian 7: Gnome3 sometimes stops when loading

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3, gdm3

Sometimes (rather rarely) when I boot up my laptop, my Gnome3 desktop stops loading. I can move the mouse, but there's nothing else on the screen (except my wallpaper). And it seems that no matter how long I wait, the gnome menubar (the thingie with the Activities and shutdown buttons at the top of the screen) just refuses to load.

Also my processor-usage starts to converge to 100% on all four cores, when this happens.

This problem can be easily solved by restarting gdm3, but it's still annoying and I have no clue why this might happen.

My system uses the standard gnome metapackage from the wheezy repo. (It might or might not be relevant.)

I have no clue what causes this so any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be issues with `gnome-shell` at various times across multiple distros ([Red Hat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=812624) for example).

Your best bet would be to browse and file a bug in [Debian BTS](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?dist=unstable;package=gnome-shell), including relevant output from `strace`, `top`, etc. Note that Debian 6 is still the [Stable](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases#Production_Releases) release and Debian 7 is [Testing](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases#Current_Releases.2FRepositories). Your help reporting and tracking the issue in BTS will help make the release more stable.